# Get User Specific Answer attribute from primary model instance - django

Tags: django

I have a Question model and then an Answer Model. Answer model saves answers specific to the logged-in user. I have successfully saved the answer of the login user and verified it in the admin. However, I am unable to get the answer, specifically for the logged-in user. Can you please point me in the right direction?
I have already tried https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/relations/

My Model:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    edit_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.question

class Answer(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    answer = models.TextField(max_length=600, null=True, blank=True, default=" ")
    edit_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.answer
```

My View

```
def InterviewQuestion(request):
    questions = Question.objects.all()
    context = {'questions':questions}
    return render(request, 'jobs/ace-interview.html', context)
```

My Template

```
{% for question in questions %}
   <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">{{question.question}}</h5>
              <p class="card-text">{{question.answer_set.answer}}</p>
      </div>
   </div>
{% endfor %}
```

[I want Answer here specific to the user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yXRW6.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to filter `Answer` based on the current user that is logged in, pass that to the template's context, and then render on your HTML page. Something along the lines of:

In your view:

```py
def InterviewQuestion(request):

    questions = Question.objects.all()

    question_answers = {}
    for question in questions:
        answer = Answer.objects.filter(user=request.user, question=question).first()
        question_answers[question] = answer

    context = {'question_answers': question_answers}
    return render(request, 'jobs/ace-interview.html', context)
```

With the above code you will now be left with a dictionary that is *specific* to the user that looks something like so (keep in mind it's not `str` for neither the key/value, but rather Django models):

```
{
    ...
    "Your name?": "Felipe",
    ...

    # Realistically, it looks something more like:
    <Question Model>: <Answer Model>

}
```

Passing the above to your context will then allow you to render the question and answer.

```html
{% for question, answer in question_answers.objects %}
   <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">{{question.question}}</h5>
              <p class="card-text">{{answer.answer}}</p>
      </div>
   </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Something along those lines should work. You might want to format the view code to your preference, and double check syntax is correct (wrote it on the fly directly on StackOverflow - no checking on my end).